# data on component but no results on view.html

Tags: node.js, angular

I´m developing a little MEAN application, I have my MongoDb. Now I try to do a simple search with a form, I send the search to the component. The component calls the back end method on the service and the method subscribe returns the results. I use the Firefox developing tools, and the object is there, but I don't know why..the results doesn't appear on the view ....I display with `*ngFor`.

input from the view

```
<form #barForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(barForm)">
    <input type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="search">search a bar
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

the component...

```
onSubmit(form){      

  var search = this.search;   
  console.log(search);

  this._barService.findBars(this.search).subscribe(

      response =>{
       console.log(response);
        if(response.pubs){
          this.bars = response.bars;
        }
      },
      error =>{
        console.log(<any>error);
      }

    )
}
```

the loop in the view...

```
<div class="bar-container">
    <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let bar of bars" class="bars">
            <a [routerLink]="['/detail',bar._id]">      
                
                <div class="bar-image">
                <img src="{{url+'/get-image/'+bar.image }}" *ngIf="bar.image">
                </div>

                <h5>{{ bar.city }}</h5>             
            </a>
        </li> 

    </ul>
</div>
```

as you see, I´trying to display the "city" property of my object...I display an screenshot to show u that the results are there...
[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is a response.pubs..? Can’t tell from the screenshot..

Comment: Can you share your service method? My guess is you're not returning the http.get or something like this. EDIT:  you are checking for response.pubs and trying to get response.subs, what MikeOne says :)

Comment: findBars(search):Observable<any>{
   let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');   
   return this._http.get(this.url+'/find-bars/'+search,{headers:headers});
  }

Answer (score 0):

your need check if the variable `bars` is declared as global
for example

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    
    public bars:any;

    constructor(){
    }

    onSubmit(form){
    }
}
```

Note
change the class name in your css, this have the equals name that your variable, this can generate a problem in a future

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply..I´ll try to post again. I habe some problems in order to post like the moderators demand...si I´ll try again...

the following code is from the component...

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BarService } from '../../services/bar.service';
import { Bar } from '../../models/bar';
import { Global } from '../../services/global';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
  providers:[BarService]
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

    public search:string;
    public bars:Bar[];
    public url:string;

  constructor(
    private _barService:BarService
    ) {
    this.url = Global.url;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  onSubmit(form){      

      var search = this.search;   
      console.log(search);

      this._barService.findBars(search).subscribe(

          response =>{
            console.log(response);
            if(response.pubs){
              this.bars = response.bars;
            }
          },
          error =>{
            console.log(<any>error);
          }

        )
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
this._barService.findBars(this.search).subscribe(
  response =>{
   console.log(response);
    if(response.pubs){
      this.bars = response.bars;
    }
  },
  error =>{
    console.log(<any>error);
  }
)
```

the mistake in your code is from backend you're getting bars (response.bars), but in ui in if condition you're verifying for pubs (response.pubs).

solution

```
 this._barService.findBars(this.search).subscribe(
  response =>{
   console.log(response);
    if(response.bars){
      this.bars = response.bars;
    }
  },
  error =>{
    console.log(<any>error);
  }
)
```

Comment: Yes!!! you are right!! I realized a couple of day ago!! ..what a silly slip...thanks a lot anyway..greeting to the community--you are great!!! :)))